# Наследование и Шаблоны

Tags: c++

Есть три класс:
interface.h

```
 template <class T>
    class interface
    {
    public:
        interface();
        virtual ~interface() = 0;
    };
```

base.h

```
template<class T>
class base : public interface<T>
{
public:
    base();
    ~base();

    T get();
public:
    T some;
};
```

derived.h

```
template<class T>
class derived : public base<T>
{
public:
    derived();
    ~derived();
};
```

Реализация классов
interface.cpp

```
   template <class T>
    interface<T>::interface()
    {
    }
```

base.cpp

```
template<class T>
base<T>::base()
{

}

template<class T>
T base<T>::get()
{
    return this->some;
}
```

derived.cpp

```
template<class T>
    derived<T>::derived()
    {

    }

    template<class T>
    derived<T>::~derived()
    {

    }
```

в файле main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    derived<QString> test();
    test.get();
    return a.exec();
}
```

на строчке test.get(); компилятор выдает ошибку: request for member 'get' in 'test', which is of non-class type 'derived<QString>()'

не могу понять в чем причина данной ошибки. Метод get - public, все наследование через public. Изначально был более сложный подобный код, выдавалась ошибка: undefined reference to `Derived<T>::Derived(QFile&)', решил упростить задачу и понять в чем дело, но наткнулся новую ошибку. Как видно из main использую Qt Creator, компилятор MinGW.

спасибо.

Comment: а если в main написать derived<QString> test;, то компилятор выдает следующее:
8: ошибка: undefined reference to `derived<QString>::derived()'
10: ошибка: undefined reference to `base<QString>::get()'

Собственно это ошибки, из-за который я и писал тестовый код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в

```
derived<QString> test();
```

Это объявляет функцию `test` без аргументов.

---

А undefined reference -- это уже другая ошибка. Ошибка компоновщика. Поместите реализацию шаблона в `.h`. Вот [объяснение](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates-defn-vs-decl.html).

Comment: Спасибо, за оперативный ответ.
Я не силен в английском, но суть понял, что компилятор компилирует файлы не одновременно, соответственно, если реализация вынесена в .cpp файл, то он просто не видит реализацию метода шаблонного класса, при компиляции файла, где уже указано, что использовать вместо шаблона. 
Но я не нашел информации о том, как это можно обойти. Если вас не затруднит - не подскажете?

Comment: Причины 2:
1. В реальном коде огромное кол-во методово, и не хотелось бы все их переносить в header. 
2. Класс Interface и Base - абстрактные(у них чисто виртуальный деструктор), а при реализация деструктора в классе Derived в header'e возникает ошибка: undefined reference to `base<QString>::~base

если есть способы обойти данное ограничение - буду рад услышать. спасибо.

Comment: @jawello: обойти можно одним из двух путей:

* либо не выносите имплементацию шаблонного класса в отдельный .cpp-файл, оставьте всё в .h (inline)
* либо в .cpp-файле с реализацией шаблонного класса перечислите **все** нужные вам инстанциации.

Мне лично первый вариант нравится больше.

Comment: спасибо еще раз. Согласен.

Comment: @jawello: Проблема с `undefined reference to base<QString>::~base` по идее правится точно так же: либо перенести реализацию `base` в base.h, либо упомянуть `base<QString>` в base.cpp.

Comment: @jawello: Кстати, в качестве простого трюка можно просто написать

    #include "base.cpp"

в _конце_ base.h и т. д. (Только не забудьте убрать `#include "base.h"` в начале base.cpp.)

Comment: @VladD, лучше еще тогда переименовать во что-нибудь вроде "base_impl.h"